# TypeError: GMaps is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to use [gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/basic.html) to display a Google Map on my website.

```
<div id="map">
    <!-- GMaps.js injection here. -->
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var map = new GMaps({
            div: '#map',
            lat: -12.043333,
            lng: -77.028333
        });
    });
</script>
```

I get the following error on Firebugs console:

```
TypeError: GMaps is not a constructor
    lng: -77.028333
```

In my _Layout.cshtml file, here are the references to jQuery and other Javascript libraries:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js">
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cassette.axd/asset/Public/assets/stylesheets/main.less?zrfwD7IeGX87BD2hXeX_19D7PM4=">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cassette.axd/asset/Public/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css?Fr-zb2zZgNbHEFtP2LHSlWzPcTc=">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cassette.axd/asset/Public/assets/javascripts/gmaps.js?l4YO_kYaJ82XSUboAjqvgNOTSog=">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cassette.axd/asset/Public/assets/javascripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js?1e4_Y6C_dosNDw5vnP_HMJnJOaI=">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cassette.axd/asset/Public/assets/javascripts/jquery.validate.js?N48SH-DQLi1ZxkCU5H4QfkU_Vqk=">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cassette.axd/asset/Public/assets/javascripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js?H9QpwLXle-pJHFboqVks8SmWPD8=">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cassette.axd/asset/Public/assets/javascripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js?5os4UsHTQvdRWuk_dD_ZJbhKv2o=">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cassette.axd/asset/Public/assets/javascripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js?VuXJYhbnFpRWN4gr3pwlAyCdWUg=">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cassette.axd/asset/Public/assets/javascripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.debug.js?HcBKh9uDD_B8LpYqpQW1dYU6woI=">
</head>
```

Any ideas why this is being fired?

Comment: Are you sure your reference to the GMaps API is correct? (/cassette.axd/asset/Public/assets/javascripts/gmaps.js)

Comment: @KevinBoucher: Yes, in fact I can even expand the referenced link using Firebug and see the source code is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

from your headers. If you look at the first line of gmaps.js, you will see

```
if(window.google && window.google.maps){
```

So, it relies upon the Google Maps API, even if it simplifies it.